# Thread inside a System.Timers.Timer method

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer

I have the following scenarios using System.Timers.Timer.

Create a Timer object and assign the method

```
_JobListener.Enabled = false;
_JobListener.Elapsed += (this.JobListener_Elapsed);
```

Within JobListener_Elapsed, I created another thread to run some functions.

```
JobListener_Elapsed
{
    //stop the timer
    _JobListener.Enabled = false; 

    System.Threading.Thread pollThread = new Thread(JobListener_ElapsedAsync);
    pollThread.Start();

    //join to the main timer thread
    pollThread.Join();

    //restart the timer
    _JobListener.Enabled = true;
}
```

Within JobListener_ElapsedAsync, I log the timer Enabled status.

```
private void JobListener_ElapsedAsync()
{
    try{
        log Timer.Enabled
        some other code
    }finally
    {
        _JobListener.Enabled = true; 
    }
}
```

However, I can see some times, it can see the timer status to be true, which is wrong. The timer should be stopped when JobListener_ElapsedAsync is running.

Any idea?

Comment: What's the point of starting a new thread if the thread starting it is just going to block until it finishes?  You might as well just run the code directly in the event handler if you're doing that.

Comment: @Servy I was asking myself the same question. It is some legacy code. I have corrected it not to use a separate thread. But I am confused by this behavior when I keep this separate thread inside the Timer method.

Comment: Where in your code do you ever enable the timer?  It needs to be enabled *somewhere*.  That code is probably being called while this is running.  You could also have multiple elapsed handlers, you could just be observing this incorrectly, your async method could be starting *another* async operation, thus resulting in the current thread continuing on to enable the timer, etc.  The simple fact is you haven't shown enough code to know what the problem is.

Comment: I agree with @Servy. It's true because it's set to true. Put breakpoints or write some trace (with thread id) wherever it's enabled and see if that code is triggered unexpectedly.

Comment: @Servy the timer is initially enabled in the class's constructor, and also in the resume method. I put some logs in them, but non of them was triggered. I mean triggered incorrectly.

Comment: @Helic That only covers some of the cases I mentioned, and it still doesn't change the fact that we don't have enough information to be helpful.  If you can create a *short* but *complete* program that can replicate the problem then perhaps we could help.  Right now my money's on you improperly observing the state though, and that it really is disabled while the work is being done.

Comment: @KaiWang It happens not very often only after a few hundreds of timer ticks. Putting a breakpoint may not be a good idea. Different threads ID should be generated in this case, isn't it?

Comment: @Servy yes, I am running a smaller test program, and hopefully it can be replicated.

Comment: @Helic, if the current JobListener_ElapsedAsync is still running it will block the Elapsed handler from enabling the timer. If the timer is enabled it must be from other handlers. I assume JobListener_Elapsed is the *only* place the timer is enabled besides the initial Start call.

Comment: How short is your interval? It's possible that elapsed is fired twice before the method sets the enabled to false.

Comment: @KaiWang the application was hosted in a windows service, that is another place where a timer could be restarted. The old code doesn't have the Join method, I think that is a problem.

Comment: Updated the code. I accidentally enabled the timer before the Join method. That is why the timer is started again.

Comment: Updated the code. I accidentally enabled the timer before the Join method. That is why the timer is started again, even the Enable statement is within the finally block

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two main classes of timer in the .NET Framework: thread timers, and window timers.

`System.Threading.Timer` is the basic class for thread timers. This wraps the Windows [waitable timer object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687012%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). The `Tick` event is fired on the `ThreadPool`. It **does not** check whether all handlers for a previous `Tick` have returned before firing `Tick` again. The timer should fire on time - it is not delayed.

`System.Windows.Forms.Timer` wraps the Windows `SetTimer` API. The `Tick` event is fired on the thread that creates the timer. If that isn't a UI thread it won't actually fire. Timers are the lowest priority messages; they are only generated by `GetMessage`/`PeekMessage` when no other messages are outstanding. Therefore they can be delayed significantly from when they should be generated.

`System.Timers.Timer` wraps `System.Threading.Timer`. If you have set its `SynchronizingObject` property to something, when the underlying timer fires, it will use `ISynchronizeInvoke.Invoke` to get onto that object's thread (analogous to `Control.Invoke` - indeed `Control` implements `ISynchronizeInvoke`). It blocks the thread pool thread in the process. If `SynchronizingObject` is `null` it just fires the `Elapsed` event on the thread pool thread. The only real use for this class is if you need timers for UI components to be fired on time. If you don't need to synchronize, use a `System.Threading.Timer` instead.

If you need to ensure that a previous `Tick` event is fully handled (all handlers have returned) before the next one is started, you need to either:

- Make the timer one-shot rather than periodic, and have the last handler set up another shot when it finishes executing
- Use a `lock` or `Monitor` to prevent two threads entering the handler (but you could use up all threads in the thread pool)
- Use `Monitor.TryEnter` to only enter the handler if the previous one has finished (but you could miss some `Tick`s).

Comment: could you explain a bit more on the solutions to fully handle the previous Tick event? Thanks.